# Animação ao expandir item em um sidebar

Tags: css3, front-end

Como criar um efeito de deslocamento a direita (dos itens) ao expandir uma opção de menu, dentro de um sidebar? É possível fazer usando apenas CSS?

Tentei usar "transition" mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Posta o código que tu tens até o momento de forma clara.

Comment: Este é o código que eu tenho atualmente:

    .side-nav>li>ul>li>a {
        animation-duration: .5s;
        animation-name: move;
    }

    @keyframes move {
        from { margin-left: 0%; }
        to { margin-left: 5%; }
    }

Eu quero obter este resultado: https://mighty-ravine-84144.herokuapp.com/html/static/dashboards-videos.html

Comment: e o qual seria HTML?

Comment: não consigo postar o conteúdo.. está excedendo o limite de caracteres.

Mas está correto. No sentido de expandir a ul (collapse).. Só não estou conseguindo o efeito nos itens do submenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS3 TRANSITION**

Aplicar transições é possível com [CSS3 Transition](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) e aplicando ao seu caso:

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  if($(".intern").css("height") != "100px") {
    $(".intern").css("height", "100px");
    $(".intern li").css("marginLeft", "0px");
  }
  
  else {
    $(".intern").css("height", "0px");
    $(".intern li").css("marginLeft", "-52px");
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  padding: 7px;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #38C;
}

.intern {
  transition: all 0.52s;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.intern li {
  transition: all 0.52s;
  margin-left: -52px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Texto</li>
  <li>Texto</li>
  <li><a>Texto</a>
    <ul class="intern">
      <li>Texto</li>
      <li>Texto</li>
      <li>Texto</li>  
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Texto</li>
  <li>Texto</li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado Thiago.

Só para complementar: também consegui solucionar desta forma:

@keyframes move {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-20%);
        transform:translateX(-20%)
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
        transform:translateX(0)
    }
}